# How to make logout page that involves session cookie using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, validation, logout

I want to create a logout.php so that it remembers the username from the login.php.

I want to use $_GET method so that it gets the session username from login and when we logout, the cookie session is logged out. And if there is no set cookie session then there will be an error saying no ones were logged in so log gout doesn't work.

The login.php does login's the user and set cookie which I checked from the browser settings.

login.php

```
<?php 

require"connection.php";
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user = $_POST['username']; 
    $password = $_POST['password'];  

  if ($user){ 
        if ($password){ 

setcookie('username', '$user', time()+3600); 
setcookie('password', '$password', time()+3600);       

          //make sure login info correct
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'"); 
                $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); 

            if ($numrows == 1) {
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); 
                 $dbuser = $row['username']; 
                 $dbpass = $row['password']; 

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Welcome, '.$user.'. A cookie session  has been created.");</script>'; 
        }else{echo "Please enter valid username or password";}
        }else {echo "Your password didn't match. Please try again";}
        }else {echo "Your username didn't match. Please try again";}
        }else {echo "Please enter username and password";}
?>
```

Comment: Simply check session on logout page, if specific session is not set, you can give an error. You dont need to use session cookie.

Comment: ..and don't forget to escape POST-data before inserting it to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this..

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['username']) && !empty($_COOKIE['username'])) {
    // Bye $_COOKIE['username'], you are logged out.
    setcookie('username', '', time() - 3600);
} else {
    // no user logged in
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to echo out the username that has been logged in and say  for example, "Bye Alex, you are logged out". Do we need $_GET command for this?